# Date project in vcpp

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

In VC++ 6.0 MFC application
i am trying to Display date in Shot Format eg;05-10-09
but it will print 05-10-2009

Here is the code i written
SYSTEMTIME st;
GetSystemTime(&st);

CString str;

str.Format("%02d-%02d-%02d",st.wDay,st.wMonth,st.wYear);
m_date=m_date + str;

I will get output say eg: 05-10-2009, but i want in this format 05-10-09

Plz any body help me

Answer (score 1):

... "%02d", st.wYear % 100 ...

Answer (score 0):

1. it should be %02d-%02d-%02d, and not %02d-%02d-**02%d**
2. The proper way should be using CTime::Format (I Don't know if VC 6 had that)
3. pass (st.Year % 100)

Comment: humm, sorry while asking question i did mistake it is %02d-%02d-%02d then also i will get output eg: 02-11-2009 , i want to display it 02-11-09 how i can do it any hint,